# Derivative of $\int_a^x \frac{1}{k^x} \: dk$

Tags: calculus

Is it possible to define a derivative for the function: $$\int_a^x \frac{1}{k^x} \: dk$$ (where a is a constant) and if so what would it be?

Comment: $(a,x)$ are constants and $k$ is variable. Right?

Answer (score 0):

If we write $\int_a^t f(x,s)ds=F(x,t)$ and $g(x)=F(x,x)$, then by the chain rule $g'(x)=F_x(x,x)+F_t(x,x)$, where $F_x(x,x)=\int_a^t f_x(x,s)ds$ and $F_t(x,x)=f(x,x)$ by the fundamental theorem of calculus.

Hence in your case $f(x,s)=s^{-x}=\exp(-x\log s)$ we have $f_x(x,s) = -\log s \exp(-x\log s) = -\frac{\log s}{s^x}$ and so 
$$
\frac{d}{dx}\int_a^x \frac1{k^x} dk = \frac1{x^x}-\int_a^x \frac{\log k}{k^x}dk.
$$

Answer (score 0):

Using the Leibniz rule,
$$\frac{d}{dx} \, \int_{a}^{b} f(x,t) \, dt = f(x,b) \, \partial_{x}b - f(x,a) \, \partial_{x}a + \int_{a}^{b} \partial_{x}f(x,t) \, dt$$
then
\begin{align}
\frac{d}{dx} \, \int_{a}^{x} \frac{dt}{t^{x}} &= \frac{1}{x^{x}} + \int_{a}^{x} \partial_{x} e^{-x \ln t} \, dt \\
&= \frac{1}{x^x} - \int_{a}^{x} \frac{\ln t}{t^{x}} \, dt
\end{align}

An alternate method may be used, that avoids the integral, or provides a value for a new integral. This is seen by the following.

Since, for $x \neq 1$, 
$$\int_{a}^{x} \frac{dt}{t^x} = \left[ \frac{t^{1-x}}{1-x} \right]_{a}^{x} = \frac{x^{1-x} - a^{1-x}}{1-x}$$
then
$$\frac{d}{dx} \, \int_{a}^{x} \frac{dt}{t^{x}} = \frac{1}{(1-x)^{2}} \, \left[ x^{1-x} \, \left(\frac{1}{x} - 1 - (1-x) \, \ln x \right) + a^{1-x} \, (\ln a - 1) \right].$$

This result also leads to
$$\int_{a}^{x} \frac{\ln t}{t^{x}} \, dt = \frac{1}{(1-x)^{2}} \, \left[ (1-x) \, x^{1-x} \, \ln\left(\frac{x}{e}\right) - a^{1-x} \, \ln\left(\frac{a}{e}\right) \right].$$